# Survey program using JSF and Ajax

Tags: java, beginner, xml, ajax, jsf

I'm new to AJAX and am trying to learn by myself with a small test:

It's a survey with 3 questions.  I would like to know if I'm using AJAX the correct way, before starting bigger projects.

Here is the question.xhtml page:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Question page</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1>Question page</h1>

        <h3>Regular HTML Form</h3>
        <h:form id="survey">
            Over: <h:outputText value="#{generalController.over}" id="testover"/><br/>
            <h:outputText id="question" value="#{generalController.getQuestion()}"/>
            <p:inputText id="answer" value="#{generalController.answer}"/><br/>
            <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Next" rendered="#{!generalController.last}">
                <f:ajax execute="answer" render="survey"/>
            </h:commandButton>
            <h:commandButton id="done" value="Finish" rendered="#{generalController.last}" action="end"/>
        </h:form>
        <br/>
        <h3>PrimeFace Form</h3>
        <h:form id="pfsurvey">
            Over: <h:outputText value="#{generalController.over}" id="testover"/><br/>
            <h:outputText id="question" value="#{generalController.getQuestion()}"/>
            <p:inputText id="answer" value="#{generalController.answer}" rendered="#{!generalController.over}"/><br/>
            <p:commandButton id="submit" value="Next" rendered="#{!generalController.last}" update="pfsurvey" actionListener="#{generalController.next}" />
            <p:commandButton id="done" value="Finish" rendered="#{generalController.last}" action="end" ajax="false" />
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

The `GeneralController` bean is:

```java
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@Named(value = "generalController")
@ApplicationScoped
public class GeneralController {

    String[] questions = {"What is your age?","Where do you come from?","Are you married?"};
    String answer;
    String question;
    int currentQuestion = 0;
    boolean over  = false;
    boolean last = false;

    public String getAnswer() {
        System.out.println("Get Answer");
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {       
        System.out.println("Set Answer");
        if(currentQuestion < questions.length) {
            System.out.println("To the question  \""+questions[currentQuestion]+"\" your answer is "+answer);
            currentQuestion++;
            if(currentQuestion == questions.length -1) last = true;
            if(currentQuestion == questions.length) over = true;
        }
    }    

    public String getQuestion() {
        System.out.println("Get Question");
        if(!over)
        return questions[currentQuestion];
        else return "";
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        System.out.println("Set Question");
        this.question = question;
    }

    public void next() {
        System.out.println("Next");
    }

    public String reset() {
        currentQuestion=0;
        over=false;
        last=true;
        return "question";
    }

    public boolean isOver() {
        return over;
    }

    public void setOver(boolean over) {
        this.over = over;
    }

    public boolean isLast() {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast(boolean last) {
        this.last = last;
    }
}
```

When the survey is done, it's redirected to the end.xhtml page:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        Survey is done ! Thank you
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="Try Again" ajax="false" action="#{generalController.reset()}"/>

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Here is the generated HTML:

Question 1:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/MenuMobile3/faces/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-humanity" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/MenuMobile3/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css?ln=primefaces&amp;v=3.1.1" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/MenuMobile3/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=3.1.1"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/MenuMobile3/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=3.1.1"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/MenuMobile3/faces/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js?ln=javax.faces&amp;stage=Development"></script>
        <title>Question page</title></head><body>
        <h1>Question page</h1>

        <h3>Regular HTML Form</h3>
<form id="survey" name="survey" method="post" action="/MenuMobile3/faces/question.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="survey" value="survey" />

            Over: <span id="survey:testover">false</span><br /><span id="survey:question">What is your age?</span><input id="survey:answer" name="survey:answer" type="text" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" /><script id="survey:answer_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('InputText','widget_survey_answer',{id:'survey:answer'});</script><br /><input id="survey:submit" type="submit" name="survey:submit" value="Next" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action','survey:answer','survey');return false" /><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="-8356752339157975334:-3520173479150310510" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
        <br />
        <h3>PrimeFace Form</h3>
<form id="pfsurvey" name="pfsurvey" method="post" action="/MenuMobile3/faces/question.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="pfsurvey" value="pfsurvey" />

            Over: <span id="pfsurvey:testover">false</span><br /><span id="pfsurvey:question">What is your age?</span><input id="pfsurvey:answer" name="pfsurvey:answer" type="text" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" /><script id="pfsurvey:answer_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('InputText','widget_pfsurvey_answer',{id:'pfsurvey:answer'});</script><br /><button id="pfsurvey:submit" name="pfsurvey:submit" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({formId:'pfsurvey',source:'pfsurvey:submit',process:'@all',update:'pfsurvey'});return false;" type="submit"><span class="ui-button-text">Next</span></button><script id="pfsurvey:submit_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('CommandButton','widget_pfsurvey_submit',{id:'pfsurvey:submit'});</script><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="-8356752339157975334:-3520173479150310510" autocomplete="off" />
</form></body>
</html>
```

Question 3:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/MenuMobile3/faces/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-humanity" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/MenuMobile3/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css?ln=primefaces&amp;v=3.1.1" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/MenuMobile3/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=3.1.1"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/MenuMobile3/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=3.1.1"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/MenuMobile3/faces/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js?ln=javax.faces&amp;stage=Development"></script>
        <title>Question page</title></head><body>
        <h1>Question page</h1>

        <h3>Regular HTML Form</h3>
<form id="survey" name="survey" method="post" action="/MenuMobile3/faces/question.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="survey" value="survey" />

            Over: <span id="survey:testover">false</span><br /><span id="survey:question">What is your age?</span><input id="survey:answer" name="survey:answer" type="text" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" /><script id="survey:answer_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('InputText','widget_survey_answer',{id:'survey:answer'});</script><br /><input id="survey:submit" type="submit" name="survey:submit" value="Next" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action','survey:answer','survey');return false" /><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="-8356752339157975334:-3520173479150310510" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
        <br />
        <h3>PrimeFace Form</h3>
<form id="pfsurvey" name="pfsurvey" method="post" action="/MenuMobile3/faces/question.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="pfsurvey" value="pfsurvey" />

            Over: <span id="pfsurvey:testover">false</span><br /><span id="pfsurvey:question">What is your age?</span><input id="pfsurvey:answer" name="pfsurvey:answer" type="text" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" /><script id="pfsurvey:answer_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('InputText','widget_pfsurvey_answer',{id:'pfsurvey:answer'});</script><br /><button id="pfsurvey:submit" name="pfsurvey:submit" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({formId:'pfsurvey',source:'pfsurvey:submit',process:'@all',update:'pfsurvey'});return false;" type="submit"><span class="ui-button-text">Next</span></button><script id="pfsurvey:submit_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('CommandButton','widget_pfsurvey_submit',{id:'pfsurvey:submit'});</script><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="-8356752339157975334:-3520173479150310510" autocomplete="off" />
</form></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Nothing to complain about. Just a minor comment on your backing bean code: I would always use brackets for if/else constructs, even if there is only on command in each branch. This improves readability and is less error prone.

Answer (score 6):

1. ```
   @ApplicationScoped
   public class GeneralController {
       ...
   }
   ```

   I think your bean should be `@SessionScoped` instead of `@ApplicationScoped`. Otherwise all of you clients will use the same controller instance.
2. Instead of an array I'd use a `List`. It's easier to work with.

   ```
   String[] questions = {"What is your age?","Where do you come from?","Are you married?"};
   ```

   [When to use a List over an Array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1589813/843804)
3. You could format the code better:

   ```
   if(!over)
   return questions[currentQuestion];
   ```

   According to the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#449) `if` statements always should use braces. Omitting them is error-prone, and hard to read if you don't indent the conditional statement like above.
4. The fields could be [private](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/143736/36726) instead of the current package private.

   > The rule of thumb is simple: make each class or member as inaccessible as
   >   possible. In other words, use the lowest possible access level consistent with the
   >   proper functioning of the software that you are writing.

   Source: *Effective Java 2nd Edition*, *Item 13: Minimize the accessibility of classes and members*, p68.